# Reference request: zeros of $L(s, \chi)$ is symmetric in the critical strip along the crirical line

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Let $\chi$ be any primitive Dirichlet character modulo $q \geq 1$.
I am looking for a reference for

i) if $L(\rho, \chi) = 0$ and $0 \leq Re(\rho) \leq 1$,  then $L(1 - \rho, \chi) = 0$.
(and that $\rho$ and $1-\rho$ have the same multiplicities in this case)

ii) $L(s, \chi) \neq 0$ for $Re(s) = 1$.

In Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory (Page 83) he mentions i) for primitive complex characters, but I haven't been able to find an explicit statement of the above fact in the book.. Any precise reference where I can find these (or an explanation) is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: The functional equation relates $L(1-s,\chi)$ and $L(s,\overline{\chi})$, so unless $\chi$ is a real-valued character, the functional equation does not connect the $L$-function to itself. So I wonder if your quoted result has a typo... Together with the identity principle, we _do_ connect $L(s,\chi)$ and $L(1-\overline{s},\chi)$... In any case, the $L$-function for a non-primitive character differs from the primitive-character case only by finitely-many Euler factors, so can't you easily derive the (correct) statement from that for primitive characters?

Comment: @paulgarrett I meant for primitive characters. typo fixed. thank you. As for your first comment, I think one can consider the complex conjugate of $L(s, \bar{\chi} )$?

Comment: @Johny T., at the moment it seems to me that the functional equation + identity theorem (fooling around with complex conjugations, as you say), relates arguments $s$ and $1-\overline{s}$ with fixed $\chi$. A reflection through the line $\Re(s)=1/2$. The $s\to 1-s$ symmetry seems to require $\chi\to \overline{\chi}$. Not that this proves there is _not_ a connection...

Comment: @paulgarrett you are right... I will check the book again. thank you

Comment: @paulgarrett The last paragraph of page 83 Davenport "We observe that, for a complex $\chi$, the zeros of $L(s, \chi)$ are still symmetric about the line $\sigma = \frac12$, since $1 - \bar{\rho} = \rho'$, but not about the real axis." Did I perhaps misinterpret this statement?

Comment: @JohnyT., Ah! As I thought. Right, symmetric (by functional equation and identity principle) across the line $\Re(s)=1/2$... (but not necessarily across the real axis). So not necessarily under $s\to 1-s$. So perhaps you misinterpreted or over-interpreted.

Comment: @paulgarrett It could just be my english but I am really confused with what the correct statements are supposed to be now... Could you maybe post as a solution what the correct statements are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functional equation relates $L(s,\chi)$ and $L(1-s,\overline{\chi})$, by $\Lambda(1-s,\chi)=\varepsilon(\chi)\cdot \Lambda(s,\overline{\chi})$, where the $\Lambda$'s are *completed* $L$-functions, and $|\varepsilon(\chi)|=1$ is the so-called $\varepsilon$-factor (generalizing the argument of a Gauss sum).

Also, using the identity principle from complex analysis, since for real $s>1$ we have $\overline{L(s,\chi)}=L(s,\overline{\chi})$, and $s\to \overline{L(\overline{s},\chi)}$ is holomorphic in $s$, for all $s$ we have
$$
\overline{L(\overline{s},\chi)} \;=\; L(s,\overline{\chi})
$$
This gives another symmetry of the zeros, but, again, relating $\chi$ and $\overline{\chi}$.

The only symmetry of zeros mentioning only $\chi$ (and not $\overline{\chi}$ is $s\to 1-\overline{s}$, which is reflection across the line $\Re(s)=1/2$.

For $\chi\not=\overline{\chi}$, we have no reason to think that the zeros of $L(s,\chi)$ are symmetrical under $s\to 1-s$, nor $s\to \overline{s}$, since both those symmetries interchange $\chi$ and $\overline{\chi}$. But applying *both* does preserve $\chi$, and gives the symmetry across the critical line.

Comment: This makes more sense now, thank you! One thing that's not clear to me is how do we know that the multiplicity of the zeros are preserved?

Comment: @JohnnyT., since all these are holomorphic functions, what may look like mere pointwise equalities are really equalities of convergent power series, so include multiplicities of zeros.